# An expression for a numerical limit

Tags: phrase-requests

I'd like to include all numbers below 10, and exclude all numbers above 10. So I'd like to **____** at 10. (make the cut? put the limit?)

I'm feeling that the expression has to do something with cutting, but I can't find the right words.

Comment: You could *.. place the upper bound at 10*

Comment: Or you could _make ten the cut-off point_. With your frame, it's usually _set the limit_.

Comment: It seems to me neither your question text nor any answers/comments indicate whether the actual value **10** should be included or not.

Comment: You stop at ten. Simple as that.

Comment: If you are including numbers below 10, and excluding numbers above 10, what are you doing with 10?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I assume it doesn't matter. If I wanted to be that exact, I guess I would use a more exact formulation for this, such as: "include all the numbers up to and including 10".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to [**draw the line**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/draw+the+line) at 10.

> [**draw the line**](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/draw+the+line.html) (at something): to set a limit at something; to decide when something has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

You could use many synonyms for the verb "end":

> break off,
>   call it quits,
>   call off,
>   cut off.
>   end,
>   halt,
>   knock it off,
>   lay off,
>   terminate

[Find loads more here.](http://thesaurus.com/browse/end)

How about

> I'd like to stop at 10?

or

> I'd like to limit it to 10?